# CocoaPod post_install in podspec isn't executed

Tags: cocoapods

I have a cocoapod podspec with pod_install actions, but I don't see it to be executed by `pod install`

Here's the podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
spec.name             = '<NAME>'
...

 def spec.post_install(target_installer)
    puts "\nRUNNING POST_INSTALL hook \n"
    system 'echo `pwd` > /tmp/e.log'
 end
end
```

Though there's no message output or /tmp/e.log file

The goal with the `system` call in post_install is to unzip big file after pod installation

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solution:

```
spec.prepare_command = <<-CMD
      ...
  CMD
```

does the job well